# Python 3 - reading files, counting, and filtering text

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a code in Python 3 with the following prompt:

Exercise 2: Write a program to prompt for a file name, and then read through the file and look for lines of the form: `X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475`. When you encounter a line that starts with `X-DSPAM-Confidence:` pull apart the line to extract the floating-point number on the line. Count these lines and then compute the total of the spam confidence values from these lines. When you reach the end of the file, print out the average spam confidence.

I have started writing my code (below), but keep getting the following error message from Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spam_lines_in_file.py", line 14, in <module>
    for line in fhand:
NameError: name 'fhand' is not defined
0587388179:ch_07_files juliecruz$
```

I'm confused because I have defined the variable 'fhand'. Any help from the experts?

```
count = 0
sum = 0
user = input('Please enter a file name')
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
         print(lines)
         count += 1
         colon_position = int(line.find(":"))
         extract = line[colon_position+1:]
         number_extract = float(extract)
         sum += number_extract
print("Extracted lines", count)
print("Sum of confidence values", sum)
print("Average of confidence values", sum/count)
```

Comment: Use the below code for right output.
count = 0
sum = 0
fhand = open("mbox-short.txt")
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
         print(line)
         count += 1
         colon_position = int(line.find(":"))
         extract = line[colon_position+1:]
         number_extract = float(extract)
         sum += number_extract
print("Extracted lines", count)
print("Sum of confidence values", sum)
print("Average of confidence values", sum/count)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `fhand` is only assigned a value if no exceptions occur.

You wrote:

```
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
```

So in the case of an exception, `fhand` is not assigned a value. Which means that when you try to iterate over it, Python throws a `NameError` as it was never defined.

Maybe what you want is to terminate in the case of an exception? For example:

```
import sys
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
    sys.exit()
```

Or assign a default value to `fhand`?

```
import sys
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
    fhand = 'Default content'
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that, if a error occurs during opening the file, then a warning message is shown "Not a valid file", but processing then continues.

In that case fhand would not be assigned a value, and there would be a `NameError`

You probably want a loop that repeatedly asks for a filename, and only `break`s out when the file has been opened successfully.

```
while True:
     name = input("filename ... ")
     try:
         fhand = open(name)
     except OSerror:   # only catch OS errors, not everything. 
         print("not a valid file") 
     else:
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

fhand is a file object

```
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
```

You can not do the following on a file object.

```
for line in fhand:
```

You would need to do this:

```
for line in fhand.readlines():
```

This isn't a problem for you yet, but it will be soon.

Your real problem is this:

When this code

```
  try: 
        fhand = open(user)
```

throws an exception, the `fhand` variable doesn't get created, so you'd need to exit in the `except` block.

```
try: 
    fhand = open(user)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in line 11 :) - change to "line"
`print(lines)`